# I am having a issue pressing a key in Putty connected to a serial interface

Tags: putty, serial

I am using a serial interface board to connect to the serial interface of my router.  I have it working great (N81, no flow control) with the exception of being able to send a keystroke.

Have tried on windows and OSX systems using different emulators.  Super sure on the N81 part, and the speed (thinking I would not be able to see the output if this was off), and have tried playing with flow control and a few other vars, no joy.

A bit more info:  Connecting a Orbi RBR50, following this link:  [Orbi Serial](https://community.netgear.com/ejquo23388/attachments/ejquo23388/Orbi/107369/1/Orbi%20Serial%20Port.pdf)

I can see everything that come across, just can't press a key.

Any ideas what to try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either the electrical connection does not make proper contact or is electrically incompatible, such as devices using different voltage levels. You need to give more info what you connected where and how.

Comment: Justme, I added some info and a link to the serial interface guide.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't get the keystroke? Could be simply that local echo is off. Do you have a second UART device, best case another USB-serial-bridge to test if your setup works?

Comment: Good point, I am using https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B075N82CDL?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details, but have ordered another brand for delivery tomorrow to see if things improve.

Comment: mashuptwice, pretty sure.  The router is counting down from 3 to abort the boot, but it never interrupts and aborts.